# How to listen form for changes first?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is reactive forms in Angular.

It allows to listen change in full form and concrete field:

```
    this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {

    });

   this.filterForm.controls["name"].valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue => {
   });
```

How to listen first whole form event, then to launch listen concrete form field?

I must be something like this:

```
this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
         this.filterForm.controls["name"].valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue => {
       });
});
```

Comment: [Tell us what your problem is rather than asking for one way of solving it](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (using RxJs):

```
this.filterForm.valueChanges.pipe(
   switchMap(() => this.filterForm.controls["name"].valueChanges)
).subscribe(selectedValue => {
  // some code
})
```